# My program solves sudoku puzzles as expected but returns undefined

Tags: javascript, recursion, sudoku

My sudoku solver seems to work when I `console.log` the final board but the solve function actually returns `undefined` when I return that board.
I want to add this program to a web application so I need to be able to return a value rather than just print the answer to the console.
This is the main function "solve"

```
// Grid -> Grid or false (unsolvaable)
// Assume grid is valid
function solve(grid){
  if (isFull(grid)){
    console.log(grid)
    return grid
  }
  let nextGridArray = nextGrids(grid)

  if (nextGridArray.length < 1){
    return false
  }

  for (let grid of nextGridArray) {
     solve(grid)
  }
}
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KevinBradley/5mv2khyr/1/)

Comment: You don't return the result of the recursive call.

Comment: concerning `return false`, is there a significant difference from returned `undefined`?

Comment: Even when you solve this, your algorithm is much too slow and much too memory consuming to solve more complex puzzles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the function passes the two `if` statements without returning, it doesn't return anything explicitly, meaning implicitly it returned `undefined`. In the for loop, if a call to `solve` is successful, you should return it:

```
// Grid -> Grid or false (unsolvaable)
// Assume grid is valid
function solve(grid){
  if (isFull(grid)){
    console.log(grid)
    return grid
  }

  let nextGridArray = nextGrids(grid)

  for (let grid of nextGridArray) {
     let solved = solve(grid);
     if (solved) {
       return solved; // Here!
     }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: The `if (nextGridArray.length < 1){` statement block is not needed. The next loop wouldn't iterate in that case.

Comment: @trincot True 'dat. I copied it as is from the OP's code, but once you take a step back and look at it as a whole, you're correct, of course. Edited and improved, thanks for the feedback!